# FindFit::nrlnum: error with FindFit

Tags: fitting, warning-messages

I am trying to write a code to fit actual data of the orbit of a star with Mathematica 8.

First I tried to write a code to fit a mock orbit, using the *Application with differential equations* (the first one) as a guide (see [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindFit.html)): in that case there is only 1 function I need two (x,y positions) for my orbit.

Here is my attempt up to now:

```
Msun = 2*10^30;
M = 4.3*10^6;
G = 6.67*10^-11;
UA = 150*10^6;
(*mock orbit*)
s = NDSolve[{Vx'[t] == (-M*G*X[t]*Msun)/(X[t]^2 + Y[t]^2)^(3/2), 
     Vy'[t] == (-M*G*Y[t]*Msun)/(X[t]^2 + Y[t]^2)^(3/2), 
     X'[t] == Vx[t], Y'[t] == Vy[t], Vx[0] == #1, Vy[0] == #2, 
     X[0] == #3, Y[0] == #4}, {Vx, Vy, X, Y}, {t, 0, 10^4}] &;

tempi = Range[0, 10^4, 10^2];
Xdat = Flatten[
   Evaluate[X[#] /. s[0, 4*10^7, 1000*UA, 500*UA]] & /@ tempi, 1];
Ydat = Flatten[
   Evaluate[Y[#] /. s[0, 4*10^7, 1000*UA, 500*UA]] & /@ tempi, 1];
dati = Transpose[{Xdat*, Ydat}];
ListPlot[dati]

(*this is the model*)
orbita[a_?NumberQ, b_?NumberQ, c_?NumberQ, d_?NumberQ, 
   e_?NumberQ] := (orbita[a, b, c, d, e] := {X, Y} /. 
     NDSolve[{Vx'[t] == (-e*G*X[t]*Msun)/(X[t]^2 + Y[t]^2)^(3/2), 
       Vy'[t] == (-e*G*Y[t]*Msun)/(X[t]^2 + Y[t]^2)^(3/2), 
       X'[t] == Vx[t], Y'[t] == Vy[t], Vx[0] == a, Vy[0] == b, 
       X[0] == c, Y[0] == d}, {Vx, Vy, X, Y}, {t, 0, 10^4}]);

FindFit[dati, 
 orbita[0, 4*10^7, 1000*UA, 500*UA, Mc][X, Y], {{Mc, 10^6}}, t]
```

I get the following error:

> FindFit::nrlnum:"The function value
>   {-7.97408*10^10+Null[{X,Y}],<<49>>,<<51>>} is not \ a list of real
>   numbers with dimensions {101} at {Mc} = {1.`*^6}."

I have also tried with:

```
FindFit[dati, 
 orbita[0, 4*10^7, 1000*UA, 500*UA, Mc][X, Y], {{Mc, 10^6}}, {X,Y}]
```

but I get another error:

> FindFit::fitc: Number of coordinates (1) is not equal to the number of
>   variables (2)

Where are my errors?

Comment: You could start by trying to fit a simpler equation. There are a lot of errors there

Comment: @belisarius Do you mean syntax errors?

Comment: No. I mean conceptual errors. Like your `orbita[]` definition and usage. You need more training on easier things

Comment: You have `:=` instead of `=` in second eq. in def. of `orbita`; you should have `{X[t], Y[t]} /. NDSolve...` and no `[X, Y]` in `FindFit`.  **But** the real question is whether `FindFit` can fit 2D output data as a function of 1D input.  It seems to do only multivariate 1D fitting; you want univariate 2D.

Comment: @MichaelE2 **But** for example `Mc`, the fitted var isn't used anywhere, and a few more errors too. The real question could be how you should approach a complex problem: one step at a time

Comment: @belisarius `Mc` is the parameter `e` in the ODE.  I think it's not far from being a solution, but I think one might have to use `FindMinimum`.  (But maybe I'm wrong.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, some slight changes to `orbita`:

```
orbita[a_?NumberQ, b_?NumberQ, c_?NumberQ, d_?NumberQ, 
   e_?NumberQ] := (orbita[a, b, c, d, e] = {X[t], Y[t]} /. 
     First@NDSolve[{Vx'[t] == (-e*G*X[t]*Msun)/(X[t]^2 + Y[t]^2)^(3/2), 
        Vy'[t] == (-e*G*Y[t]*Msun)/(X[t]^2 + Y[t]^2)^(3/2), 
        X'[t] == Vx[t], Y'[t] == Vy[t], Vx[0] == a, Vy[0] == b, 
        X[0] == c, Y[0] == d}, {Vx, Vy, X, Y}, {t, 0, 10^4}]);
```

Memoization (or caching; see [`FindFit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FindFit.html) documentation: [1](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindFit.html#246277593) [2](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindFit.html#703708898)) is done with `=`; the `:=` causes the return value to be `Null` and is the source of your first error message.  The other problem is the what to return.  I suggest `{X[t], Y[t]}`, with the variable `t` in place.  I'd also strip an extra set of braces `{}` with `First@NDSolve...`.

Second, I don't think `FindFit` will work on 2D univariate data (`{x, y}` as a function of `t`).  At least I could find no example and a naive toy trial failed.  So use `FindMinimum` to minimize the sum of squares.  The objective function is given by

```
ClearAll[obj];
obj[Mc_?NumericQ] := 
 Total[#.# & /@ ((orbita[0, 4*10^7, 1000*UA, 500*UA, Mc] /. t -> # & /@
        tempi) - dati)]
```

Then minimize:

```
{min, sol} = FindMinimum[obj[Mc], {Mc, 10^6}]
```

> FindMinimum::lstol: The line search decreased the step size to within the tolerance specified by AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal but was unable to find a sufficient decrease in the function. You may need more than MachinePrecision digits of working precision to meet these tolerances. >>

```
(*  {1.54869*10^9, {Mc -> 4.3*10^6}}  *)
```

Inspect the solution to see if the warning is significant.

```
Show[
 ParametricPlot[
  orbita[0, 4*10^7, 1000*UA, 500*UA, Mc] /. sol, {t, 0, Max[tempi]}, 
  PlotStyle -> None, Mesh -> {tempi}, 
  MeshStyle -> {PointSize[Large], Red}],
 ListPlot[dati]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It does not look too bad.